# drupal7 custom form drop down show 0

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

I get a problem with my dropdown that shows "--select--","0","foods","meals" when I developing custom form with drupal7. The purpose of my dropdown is used to show "foods" and "meals" from category table. How does this "0" come from? I am hoping anyone suggestion to fix it.
Thanks,

Comment: Did you create the form through the interface or by code with form API?

Comment: Can you past the code for your `select` form item?